# Proof of the Dirichlet–Dini Criterion for Pointwise convergence of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, pointwise-convergence

I have tried and failed to prove the Dirichlet–Dini Criterion  for Pointwise convergence of Fourier series which is as follows ([source: Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence))

> if $f$ is $2\pi$–periodic, locally integrable and satisfies
> $$
> \int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{f\left(x_{0}+t\right)+f\left(x_{0}-t\right)}{2}-\ell\right| \frac{\mathrm{d} t}{t}<\infty,
> $$
> Then $S_nf(x_0)\to \ell$.

I will appreciate a proof for this theorem or a reference to one - I couldn't do either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm gonna simplify the problem by assuming that $\ell=x_0=0$: notice that
$$
\dfrac{f(x_0+t)+f(x_0-t)}{2}-\ell = \dfrac{(f(x_0+t)-\ell)+(f(x_0-t)-\ell)}{2}.
$$
Hence Dini hypothesis is the same as saying that the function $f_1(t) = f(x_0+t)-\ell$ satisfies
$$
\int^{2\pi}_0\left|\dfrac{f_1(t)+f_1(-t)}{2}\right|\dfrac{dt}{t}<\infty.
$$
As it's proved later in the lemma, translating functions by a complex number $\ell$ and translating the axis $[0,2\pi]$ by $x_0$ acts nicely on the corresponding Fourier series so, if I can find the limit of $S_N(f_1;0)$, I can find the limit of $S_N(f;x_0)$ as well. Thus I'll proof the case $\ell= x_0 =0$ and then use this "nice action" for the general case. Consider
$$
g(t)=\dfrac{f(t)+f(-t)}{1-e^{i t}} 
$$
Let'us see that $g$ is integrable.
Notice that $h(t) = \dfrac{t}{1-e^{it}}$ is continuous at $[0,2\pi]$ (using Hôpital for instance) and take
$$
K=\max_{[0,2\pi]} h(t)<\infty.
$$
Now
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\left|g(t)\right|\,dt= \int^{2\pi}_0\left|\dfrac{f(t)+f(-t)}{t}\right|\left |h(t)\right| \,dt\leq 2K\int^{2\pi}_0\left|\dfrac{f(t)+f(-t)}{2}\right| \,\dfrac{dt}{t}
$$
which is finite by hypothesis, thus it's integrable.

Compute now $\hat f(n)+\hat f(-n)$ for every $n$. Notice that
\begin{align*}
\hat f(n)+\hat f(-n)&=\int ^{2\pi}_0 f(t)e^{-itn}\,dt + \int ^{2\pi}_0 f(t)e^{itn}\,dt\\
 &\overset{(*)}{=}\int ^{2\pi}_0 f(t)e^{-itn}\,dt+\int ^{2\pi}_0 f(-t)e^{-itn}\,dt\\
 &=\int ^{2\pi}_0 (f(t)+ f(-t))e^{-itn}\,dt\\
 &=\int ^{2\pi}_0 g(t)(1-e^{it})e^{-itn}\,dt\\
 &=\hat g(n)-\hat g(n-1).
\end{align*}
I used in $(*)$ the change of coordinates $t\rightarrow t-2\pi$ for the second integral (recall that $e^{it}$ and $f_1(t)$ are $2\pi$- periodic).
In particular
$$
2S_N(f;0)= 2 \sum_{|n|\leq N} \hat f (n)=\sum_{|n|\leq N}\hat f(n)+\hat f(-n)=\hat g(N)-\hat g(-N-1).
$$
since we got a telescoping sum. Riemann-Lebesgue lemma applies to $g(t)$, hence
$$
\lim_{|N|\rightarrow \infty}\hat g(N) = 0
$$
and
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} 2S_N(f;0) = 0=\ell.
$$
For the **general case** reduce to the first one by considering $f_1(t)=f(t+x_0)-\ell$. Indeed
$$
\int^{2\pi}_0\left|\dfrac{f_1(t)+f_1(-t)}{2}\right| \,\dfrac{dt}{t}=\int^{2\pi}_0\left|\dfrac{f(t+x_0)+f(-t+x_0)-2\ell}{2}\right| \,\dfrac{dt}{t}
=\int^{2\pi}_0\left|\dfrac{f(t+x_0)+f(-t+x_0)}{2}-\ell\right| \,\dfrac{dt}{t}
$$
which is finite by hypothesis.
By the discussion above
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}S_N(f_1;0) = 0.
$$
It remains to point out that

**Lemma**

$S_N(f_1;0) = S_N(f;x_0) - \ell$ for every $N\geq 0$.

*Proof*

\begin{align*}
\hat f_1(n)&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 f_1(t) e^{-itn}\,dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 (f(t+x_0)-\ell) e^{-itn}\,dt\\
&\overset{(*)}{=}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 (f(t)-\ell) e^{-itn+ix_0n}\,dt\\
&=\dfrac{e^{ix_0n}}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 (f(t)-\ell) e^{-itn}\,dt\\
&=e^{ix_0n} \hat f(n) - \dfrac{e^{ix_0n}\ell}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0e^{-int}\,dt
\end{align*}
I use at (*) the change of variables $\,t\rightarrow t-x_0$ and that $t\mapsto e^{-int}$ is $2\pi$-periodic.
Thus
$$
\hat f_1(n)=
\begin{cases}
e^{ix_0n}\hat f(n),\quad \text{if $n\neq0$}\\
\hat f(0) -\ell,\quad \text{if $n= 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
In particular

\begin{align*}
S_N(f_1;0)&=\sum_{|n|\leq N} \hat f_1(n) e^{in 0}\\
&=\sum_{|n|\leq N} \hat f_1(n)\\   
&=\hat f(0)-\ell+\sum_{0<|n|\leq N} \hat f(n)e^{inx_0}\\
&=S_N(f; x_0)-\ell
\end{align*}
**QED**

Hence,
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}S_N(f;x_0) -\ell=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}S_N(f_1;0)=0.
$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how does this proof actualy proves the theorem? And why could you say in the beginning that you assume WLOG that x_0 = l = 0? Thanks

Comment: Edited. I've added the details for the general case. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Can you please explain why is the inequality ∫ 2π 0 |g(t)|dt≤∫ 2π 0 ∣ ∣ ∣ f(t)+f(−t)t ∣ ∣ ∣ |h(t)|dt correct?

Comment: In fact it is an equality. Multiply the right Hand Side and simplify $t$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you solve it for the general case when l and x_0 aren't 0?

Comment: Edited. I've added more details.

Comment: Can you explain the intuition of how you decided to define the function f1 and why does it work? Also - whis is this correct - "By the discussion above lim N→∞ S N (f 1 ;0)=0. " ?

Comment: Also - how exactly can I prove that f ^ (n)+f ^ (−n)=g ^ (n)−g ^ (n−1).

Comment: #eduard, i will appreciate if you will clarify the issues I have asked about in the last 2 comment. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, busy week. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Ok, I think i got it this time - just a few little clarifications: - 1) There is a mistake here - 2S N (f;0)=2∑ |n|≤N f ^ (n)=∑ |n|≤N f ^ (n)+f ^ (−n) right? the index of the last part is supposed to be n<=N and not |n|≤N.                                                          Question 2) How did you come up with the function g(t)? It looks so random yet somehow it works.

Comment: Last but not least - I have never seen how to reduce the general case to the easy 0 case - it works here because I can simply use the f_1 function to define g(t) and simply to repeat the proof of the 0 case for the general case using f_1 instead of f and it will simply work, right?

Comment: For the first question I must say that it's correct how I wrote it. In the second inequality I'm using that $2\sum_{|n|\leq N} \hat f(n)=\sum_{|n|\leq N} \hat f(n)+\sum_{|n|\leq N} \hat f(n)=\sum_{|n|\leq N} \hat f(n)+\sum_{|n|\leq N}\hat f(-n)$ just by change of coordinates.

Comment: I don't really know how I came up with function $g$. I solved this problem last year and I inspired the proof in another proof related with pointwise convergence for differentiable functions. There is where $g$ appeared. I'm afraid I cannot give references for that.

Comment: This trick of taking $\ell=x_0 =0$ is common in analysis. Mainly, you are working here in an $L_1$ space containing $\mathbb C$ (the space of integrable functions in $[0,2\pi]$). So you may add constants without restriction. Moreover, the fact they ask you to proof that $\lim_N S_N(f;x_0)=\ell$ should warn you that translating $f$ by $\ell$ will probably "simplify" the problem and allow you to write less constants while the proving.

Comment: Ok, I now understand the second equality, but why did you have 2S N (f;0) in the first place instead of just S N (f;0)? Also - what does "translating f  by ℓ" mean and why the fact that I need to calculate lim N S N (f;x 0 )=ℓ  for R([0,2pi]) functions (we didn't study Lp spaces) means that I can add constants without restriction (and what does it mean)?

Comment: The number 2 is nedeed, if it's not there the equality is false: just write it for $N=3$ and you'll see. By adding constants without restriction I meant that $f(t)$ is integrable iff $f(t)+\ell$ so you will be able to compute Fourier coefficients of $f(t)+\ell$. Whatever, I assumed the $0$ conditions and tried to solve the problem. I managed and then tried to generalize it. Of course $f_1$ did all the work.

Comment: Can you please explain what wouldn't work without the multiplication by 2? This equality is true with and without 2 -  S N (f;0)=∑ |n|≤N f ^ (n). Also  what does "translating f by ℓ" mean? Thanks

Comment: When I say translating f by ℓ I meant translating f by −ℓ which means adding −ℓ to the function f. I do need the 2 because I want to use $\hat f(n) + \hat f(-n) = \hat g(n)-\hat g(n-1)$. Thus, suming on $|n|\leq N$ I get
$$
\sum_{|n|\leq N}( \hat f(n) + \hat f(-n))=\sum_{|n|\leq N}(\hat g(n)-\hat g(n-1)).
$$
Then the left hand side is $2 S_N(f;0)$ (by change of coordinates, as I explained) and the right hand side equals $\hat g(N) - \hat g(-N-1)$ since it's a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 2):

See A. Zygmund, Trigonometric Series, Third edition, Volumes I & II combined, Cambridge Mathematical Library, Cambridge University Press, 2002 on page 52.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article might help you. Pointwise Convergence of Fourier Series, Charles Fefferman, Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 98, No. 3 (Nov., 1973), pp. 551-571:

http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970917?sid=21105651264483&uid=4&uid=2&uid=3737760

Answer (score 0):

Start with convergence criterion:
A necessary and sufficient condition for the Fourier series *T(x)* of  *f*  to converge pointwise to *c(x)* on E  is that there exists a fixed $\delta$ such that $ 0 < \delta < \pi$ and
$\int_0^\delta  {{g_{c(x)}}(u)\frac{{\sin \left( {nu} \right)}}{u}du \to 0} $  pointwise on E.

Here ${g_{c(x)}}(u) = \frac{1}{2}\left( {f(x + u) + f(x - u) - 2c(x)} \right)$.

If $\frac{{{g_c}(u)}}{u}$ is integrable,which is your given condition then by the  the Riemann Lebesgue Theorem,$\int_0^\delta  {{g_{c(x)}}(u)\frac{{\sin \left( {nu} \right)}}{u}du \to 0} $. This proves pointwise convergence. Here you can take any  $\delta > 0$.

For details see convergence criterion and Theorem 25 in

*Convergence of Fourier Series*

https://037598a680dc5e00a4d1feafd699642badaa7a8c.googledrive.com/host/0B4HffVs7117IbmZ2OTdKSVBZLVk/Fourier%20Series/Convergence%20of%20Fourier%20Series.pdf