# (Uniform) convergence rate of fourier series under Holder-continuity

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f \in C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{T})$ be a holder-continuous function, i.e.
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \le C|x-y|^{\alpha}
$$
for some $0 < \alpha < 1$. We use $\|f\|_{C_\alpha}$ to denote the smallest positive constant that the above inequality hold.

Let $S_N(f)$ be the partial sum of the fourier series of $f$, and I want to show the following inequality
$$
\|S_N(f) - f\|_\infty = \sup_x\left|\int_{-0.5}^{0.5} \frac{\sin(2N+1)\pi t}{\sin \pi t} (f(x-t)-f(x)) \mathrm{d} t\right| \lesssim \frac{\log N}{N^{\alpha}}\|f\|_{C_\alpha}
$$
holds. In other words, I want to determine the precise **rate** of uniform convergence.

The rate can be found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Uniform_convergence.

My approach is to break the interval into two parts: $|x| < \delta$ and $\delta < |x| < 0.5$. In the first part we will apply the condition of Holder continuity, and in the second part we will apply Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma; finally I choose an appropriate $\delta$ to make the sum small. However, the obtained rate is slower than $N^{-\alpha}$. And I couldn't figure out how to get the $\log(N)$ term involved. Such issue also appears in another answer
[How to show for $\alpha\in (0,1)$, any $f\in C^\alpha([0,1]/{\sim})$ has a Fourier series $S_nf$ uniformly converging to $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012365/how-to-show-for-alpha-in-0-1-any-f-in-c-alpha0-1-sim-has-a-fouri).

Any help/comment would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Find another framework to prove the above theorem. Let $T_N(x)$ be a trigonometric polynomial of order $N$ such that $\|f-T_N\|_{\infty} < \epsilon$, then by estimation the $L_1$-norm of the dirichlet kernel we can get the $\log{N}$ factor. So it suffices to find a trigonometric polynomial to approximate $f$ to the order of $N^{-\alpha}$. A natural idea is to use the cesano sum, but I can only get a rate of  $(-\alpha+\alpha^2)$, which is worse than the required rate $-\alpha$.

Comment: The construction of $N^{-\alpha}$ approximation can be found at P76 in http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~mk/approx1011/carothers.pdf.